# How to match file extension of file on specific path with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the file extension of multiple file paths with the same directory but not from other directories.

Here are two file paths I encounter.

**Path I want to match:**

```
url: "#/dist/js/core/filename.js",
```

**Path I don't want to match:**

```
url: "#/assets/knockout/filename.js",
```

What I'm trying to do is select `.js` when the file path is equal to `/dist/js/core/`.

I don't seem to find any way to account for the file name that is different every time.

I have tried using positive lookbehind but this will not account for the file name and you can't use a lookbehind with someting like `.+` because it has a non-fixed width.

```
(?<=dist\/js\/core\/)\.js
```

Comment: What is the language? Try `(?<=^#\/dist\/js\/core\/[^\/]*)\.js` https://regex101.com/r/q6qg0g/1 or use a capturing group  `\/dist\/js\/core\/[^\/]*(\.js)`  https://regex101.com/r/0H1ea4/1

Comment: In this case i'm using the find and replace in visual studio 2019. But I found a working regex. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a regex that will work form this regex will work for me.

```
(?<=dist\/js\/core\/.+)\.js
```

Pretty stupid, on regex101.com I forgot to switch from PCRE to ECMAScript. So i got the error that I can't use `.+` in a lookbehinde because it doesn't have a fixed width.

Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `/(?<!(knockout|not_this|or_this).*)[a-zA-z0-9-_]+\.js/gm`

It looks heavy but it is in fact very simple, it will basically:

1. `(?<!(knockout|not_this|or_this).*)`: Ensure that "knockout" or "not _this" or "or_this" are **not** present before the rest of the regex.
2. `[a-zA-z0-9-_]+\.js/gm`: Look for a valid filename that ends with ".js"

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PLzO41/1